# ButterKnife does not injects views for MyFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, runtimeexception, butterknife

Something is wrong with ButterKnife injection. Upon starting my app, I'm getting below error:

```
01-23 11:35:36.229  23663-23663/lt.andro.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: lt.andro.myapp, PID: 23663
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for MyNewFragment{528796ec #0 id=0x7f0a017c android:switcher:2131362172:1}
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:263)
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:207)
        at lt.andro.myapp.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.java:66)
        at lt.andro.myapp.MyNewFragment.onViewCreated(MyNewFragment.java:117)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:961)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.
```

Looks like all ButterKnife's @InjectView types are correct, but still ButterKnife is unable to inject views for my new fragment.

My layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and my new fragment has this @InjectViews:

```
@InjectView(R.id.swipe_refresh) SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.recycler) RecyclerView list;
```

Comment: did u include ButterKnife.inject(this)  in onCreate method

Comment: It's included in `onViewCreated` method.

Comment: can u post your code

Comment: Can you try/catch the exception and call `e.getCause().printStackTrace()` and paste that?

Answer (score 1):

In a fragment you should use it in onCreateView(...)

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meh, container, false);
ButterKnife.inject(this, v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to **check other ButterKnife's annotations** like `@OnItemClick`. I've used it for a RecyclerView, which was causing that RuntimeException for me.

Answer (score 0):

It also pays to watch any bindings you are injecting from within the injected view that throws the error.

In my instance I had a fragment **foo** that injected a view **bar**

```
// Foo.java
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar, container, false);
ButterKnife.inject(this, v);
```

This was throwing the described error.  It turns out that in **foo** I was binding to an element in **baz** that I expected to find inside my injected view **bar**.

```
// Foo.java
@InjectView(R.id.baz)
TextView filterTextView;
```

Except I had a typo in 'baz' in the layout xml for **bar**

```
// bar.xml
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/bazz"
/>
```

And this caused `Unable to inject views for...`